# Not-endless Recursion without a base case

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source

Write a recursive function/program, to calculate either the **Factorial** or the **Fibonacci** number of a given non-negative integer, without explicitly implementing the base case(s).

Your program/function must return/output the correct value in a reasonable time.

**You cannot**

1. Use `if` statement anywhere in your program/function, nor `switch`
   nor short-if-syntax (`?:`). Not even loops. Basically all
   control-flow statements are forbidden.
2. Use `try, catch` or exceptions of any kind.
3. Terminate the program (anything like `exit(1)`).
4. Use external sources (file, web, etc.)
5. Avoid recursion and return the proper value otherwise. (Your function must be recursive).
6. Use any of the [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny).

**You can**

- Use polymorphism, create threads, wrap the Integer type with your own class, or use any other mechanism your language or runtime has. (I can think of a solution that uses the *lazy-evaluation*, for instance). The function/program can be written as more than one function, using [Mutual Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion), if it helps you.

Please provide a **short** explanation of what you did.

Be creative! The winning answer is the one with the most upvotes by 2014-06-23 (a week from today).

**EDIT**:

Some clarifications:

Using Pattern Matching in Functional Programming Languages is OK since it's considered as Polymorphism. The solution should be trivial though, so I guess it won't have the chance to win, since it is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). It is still a legitimate answer.

Although some may say it's flow control in disguise, using *lazy evaluation*, (or *short circuit evaluation*) is allowed as well.

Comment: Possibly a remote duplicate of [this post on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4568645/1633117). I think a lot of answers there could be easily adapted to be valid submissions for this challenge.

Comment: The linked definition of control flow is such that any program with no control flow statements and with a recursive call must recurse infinitely. To avoid arguments, this needs a more precise definition of exactly what is permitted and what is forbidden, and it needs to cover all the language paradigms which people might want to use.

Comment: The question should clarify whether or not it's legit to use functional languages' pattern matching, since factorial functions without apparent flow control are a textbook example for those.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. If needed, this question can be protected or closed, as you see fit.
I removed the link.
I added a restriction for Functional languages.

Comment: Lazy evaluation is a hidden flow control, really. It feels like cheating.

Comment: @Jacob are you refusing clarification? Closing.

Comment: @Davor you need _some_ kind of flow control to do this

Comment: "super-trivial-natural solution for this" - this rule is super-unclear

Comment: Alright, I will modify it to something more specific to clarify.

Comment: @Jacob: Could you clarify how pattern matching is polymorphism?  A link would be fine, I've just not seen such a treatment before.

Comment: This seems very language specific and it seems to be about how to write `if` any other than the standard way.  E.g. is the [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) function of Mathematica permissible?  What about short circuiting `&&`?  What's not clear to me here is the *principle* behind accepting or rejecting a solution.  You only have a list of acceptable solution, most of which apply only to certain languages.  Less usual constructs that might be specific to a language are not mentioned.

Comment: The principle is trying to have an implicitly base case, if any at all. It's not a language specific - if you have a Condition method in Mathematica it's acceptable as well as the ?? operator in C#. I just want it to be a creative kind of task. For example you can set a timeout to a thread and run it without a base case. It does not have to be cheating the rules all the time... I expect more creative answers regardless the language, that's all :)

Comment: what do you mean by not using exception? what if my program will "accidently" throw exception?

Comment: I meant what I said - using exceptions to accomplish the task is not acceptable.

Comment: Honest question, is it possible to compute the elements of series like Fibonacci and factorial, without having a starting point, "without explicitly implementing the base case(s)"?

Comment: No. But that's where the creativity kicks in. Do it implicitly like some of the answers below

Comment: @Anton, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism

Comment: @Jacob: I fail to see how this has anything to do with pattern-matching (nor with case expressions, which is what pattern-matching desugars to).

Answer (score 12):

## C - factorial

simple as that

```
int not_factorial(int n){return 1;}
int factorial(int n)
{
    int (*maybe_factorial[])(int) = {factorial, not_factorial};
    return n*maybe_factorial[!(n-1)](n-1);
}
```

the function factorial is almost like a basic recursive approach but not_factorial only returns 1.
If I create an array of function pointers
(0: fac, 1: not_fac), then I can control which one should be executed at the next call:
`maybe_factorial[0](n-1)` calls factorial
`maybe_factorial[1](n-1)` calls not_factorial.
`!(n-1)` means `if n > 1 return 0 else return 1`

Comment: Can you explain a bit how this works?

Comment: Upvoted for the sheer nerve to use this method in C, of all languages ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript

Just a quick idea to get things going, nothing too fancy:

```
var t = [1];

function factorial (n) {
    var h = arguments[1] ||  1;
    t.push (t[t.length-1] * h);
    return t[n] || factorial (n,h+1);
}
```

This should be considered a program rather than a function, because it depends on a variable that is outside the function's scope (and it only works once), but I'll try to edit it later as a proper closure.

The trick here relies on the combination of JS's lazy evaluation and the fact that undefined object properties are merely an `undefined` value rather than a reason to throw an error. Rather than doing a boring recursion down from `n` to 0, I've decided to add a "secret" second parameter (`arguments[1]`) as a counter from 1 to `n`. Each iteration multiplies the last element of the `t` array by the counter, to fill the array with all the factorial values, and once the array has an `n`th element I stop the recursion and return it.

Comment: Short circuit evaluation looks suspiciously like control flow.

Comment: @James_pic True, but the question specifically mentions it as valid.

Comment: excuse me but `h = arguments[1] ||  1` means 
`h = arguments[1] ? arguments[1] :  1` and this applies to the second occurrence also. (i may be wrong but i always used it this way)

Comment: @bebe `h = arguments[1] ||  1` does not control the flow. It's just an operator, with two pretty simple operands. By this logic, I shouldn't be able to use any operators at all, because their result depends on the operands' values, e.g. 1+1 does not give the same result as 2+2. As for the second occurrence, as I said, the question specifically mentioned it as valid.

Comment: Technically, `||` can control flow (try `0 || alert("OH NOES")` versus `1 || alert("OH NOES")`)

Comment: @James_pic in js code golfing, || substitutes if(!something) and && substitutes if(something)
it's up to OP, if he allows it (for some reason) or not though.

Comment: I'd have to agree: `||` is flow control.

Comment: @svidgen I have no idea why you people are wasting your time arguing against something which the question explicitly mentions as valid. Also I really hope you realize that it's literally impossible to end a recursion without some form of flow control hidden in some level of the abstraction. Someone, somewhere, somehow, will have to use a conditional jump instruction, and the only difference between hiding it behind a logical operator and hiding it behind pattern matching is to be decided by the OP. Who, you might have noticed, has explicitly decided that it's valid.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Thanks to pattern matching, there is no need for control structures in this function.

As [Tal mentionned](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/not-endless-recursion-without-a-base-case#comment66984_31830), this is a textbook example for functional languages, one of the first shown when learning them.

Comment: Since the OP specifically allowed poymorphism, and Haskell implements polymorphism via run-time pattern matching, this seems legit.

Comment: "Recursion without a base case" - isn't `fib 0 = 0` base case?

Comment: @Davor: There is no control flow statement here, so I think this entry is valid.

Comment: Yes, but there is a base case. You need to obey all the rules, not just some.

Comment: @Davor : None of the 6 "You cannot"-rules are broken here. This entry is as valid as the other ones, and all of them define a base case.

Comment: There will always be a base case @Davor. Either you need to put it explicitly, or use the one given by you for the platform. There's no way around it. Look at the Scala answer `0 #:: 1 #::`, TCL `proc 0 ...` `proc 1 ...`, C++ `int Int<0>::Fact()`, C `int not_factorial(int n){return 1;}`, JS `||  1`. There will *always* be a base case.

Answer (score 4):

## C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int K>
class Int
    {
    public :
        int Fact(void);
    };

template<>
int Int<0>::Fact()
    {
    return 1;
    }

template<int K>
int Int<K>::Fact()
    {
    Int <K-1> x;
    return K*x.Fact();
    }

int main(void)
    {
    Int<5> A;

    cout << A.Fact() << endl;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are *explicitly implementing the base case* though, which is proscribed in the first paragraph of the question ?

Comment: As I understand the question, _explicitly implementing the base case_ means writing something like `if (K==0) return 1;`. All answers define 0! or 1! in a way. Mine could be more obfuscated, though.

Comment: You may be right - the question is not very clear.

Answer (score 4):

## Python

```python
f = lambda n: int(n==0) or n*f(n-1)
```

We exploit the short-circuiting behavior of `or`. For `n=0`, the base-case check returns true, which is converted to the int `1`, and otherwise, the `or` expression evaluates to the recursive expression.

Comment: Fun fact, `True == 1 and False == 0` so the int is redundant.

Comment: @TheRare I know, but someone might say that True is the wrong value for the factorial of 0 even though it converts to 1 in any arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala

Would this be the lazy solution the OP alluded to?

```
// Factorial
lazy val fac: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: Stream.from(1).map{i => i * fac(i - 1)}
// Fibonacci
lazy val fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: Stream.from(2).map{i => fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2)}
```

Creates a lazily evaluated stream. The first elements are hard-coded, but subsequent elements are defined recursively, with no control flow. As a side effect, values are memo-ised.

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl

Well, if we can't use `if` or `switch` or `for` or `while` to test then it looks like we'll have to implement our own **if**.

I personally feel re-implementing `if` is a bit more impressive than polymorphism because polymorphism (or function overloading) is still using built in language feature. What I'm doing is implementing a feature from scratch!

```
# First we write functions called 0 and 1
proc 0 {a b} {uplevel 1 $b}
proc 1 {a b} {uplevel 1 $a}

# Now we try to implement IF, we'll call it _I_F_
proc _I_F_ {statement a b} {
    uplevel 1 [list [expr $statement] $a $b]
}

# Now lets write a recursive countdown function
# using our scratchbuilt if:
proc countdown {number} {
    puts $number
    _I_F_ "$number>0" "count [expr $number-1]" "puts done"
}

# Lets see if it works:
countdown 10 ;# should count down to 0
```

Notes:

- `uplevel` is like evel only it allows you to execute the code in any stack level you chose.
- Tcl always expects a function name to be the first word of a statement. Therefore if you want to evaluate something like `$a>$b` or `$a==$b` you can't because you can't start a statement with a variable. That's what `expr` is for - it's a function that evaluates expressions.
- Comparison expressions such as `$a<$b`, like in other languages, return true or false. In tcl true is canonically 1 and false is canonically 0. So the `expr $statement` returns 0 or 1.
- We then construct a statement using `list` which, depending on the `expr` will start with 0 or 1 and uplevel it. This in turn executes either the function `0` or the function `1`.